# Configuring cyrus to use oauth2 via keycloak with ldap backend?

Tags: imap, single-sign-on, sasl, cyrus, oauth

We are using cyrus (and exim) as a long-running mail server. The requirement to store passwords in email programs seems to be a security risk to me. I would like to move auth behind something like keycloak, however, I fail to find good hints related to imap (and smtp the only protocol apart from http and ssh we need)

I found cyrus sasl plugins that seem to support XOAUTH2 headers like: https://github.com/moriyoshi/cyrus-sasl-xoauth2 . However, those seem to only exist in order to do some proxying with google and seem to require to store tokens.

Is there any way to set up SSO with cyrus imapd?

Comment: I actually found a cyrus sasl implementation that can check keycloak: https://github.com/atsushi0804/cyrus-sasl-xoauth2